# Google Apps Script : Multiple IF statements in a function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

I'm trying to wrap my apps script function with an if statement that contains multiple conditions.
For example:
if (a=="") {a = w} but also if (b=="") {b = w} etc until var r

So yes, many conditions but all leading to the variable being = to w. How can I set this for a whole function ?

I placed a bunch of if statements before but the 2 action blocks but they won't take the ifs into consideration it seems, I'm so confused :(

UPDATE: Here is the whole script for further clarification:

```
   function myFunction2()  {     
var brandlogosheet = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kTEoHil6FFLh2ydXaJ9RlU2n5uv9KPjrAhbQY_8hZXE/edit#gid=1309887859"
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(brandlogosheet);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('imagescript');
var values = sheet.getRange('A2:DY3').getValues();
var slides =  SlidesApp.openById("1pFq0ogk1g1_rXxkahOuvAnksysWShozOet6CzF4BcIk"); // SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
var defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();

values.forEach(function (page) {
  if (page[0]) {
    var a = page[0];
    var b = page[1];
    var c = page[2];
    var d = page[3];
    var e = page[4];
    var f = page[5];
    var g = page[6];
    var h = page[7];
    var i = page[8];
    var j = page[9];
    var k = page[10];
    var l = page[11];
    var m = page[12];
    var n = page[13];
    var o = page[14];
    var p = page[15];
    var q = page[16];
    var r = page[17];
    var ss = page[18];
    var t = page[19];
    var u = page[20];
    var v = page[21];
    var w = page[22];
    var marques = defaultSlides[8];
    var focus = defaultSlides[9];
    var themespictos = defaultSlides[7];
    var nav = defaultSlides[10];

    // So that it places a white square when it doesn't find the image URL (w = url of a white square)
    if (a=="") {
    a = w }
    if (b=="") {
    b = w }
    if (c=="") {
    c = w }
    if (d=="") {
    d = w }
    if (e=="") {
    e = w }
    if (f=="") {
    f = w }
    if (g=="") {
    g = w }
    if (h=="") {
    h = w }
    if (i=="") {
    i = w }
    if (j=="") {
    j = w }
    if (k=="") {
    k = w }
    if (l=="") {
    l = w }
    if (m=="") {
    m = w }
    if (n=="") {
    n = w }
    if (o=="") {
    o = w }
    if (p=="") {
    p = w }
    if (q=="") {
    q = w }
    if (r=="") {
    r = w }

   
    marques.getShapes().forEach(s => {
      var obj = { "{{T1_Marque1}}": a, "{{T1_Marque2}}": b,"{{T1_Marque3}}": c,"{{T1_Marque4}}": d,"{{T2_Marque1}}": e,
      "{{T2_Marque2}}": f,"{{T2_Marque3}}": g,"{{T2_Marque4}}": h,"{{T3_Marque1}}": i,"{{T3_Marque2}}": j,"{{T3_Marque3}}": k,
      "{{T3_Marque1}}": l,"{{N1}}": ss,"{{N2}}": t,"{{N3}}": u };
      var text = s.getText().asString().trim();
      if (obj[text]) s.replaceWithImage(obj[text]);
    }); 

    focus.getShapes().forEach(s => {
      var obj = { "{{Tselect_Marque1}}": m, "{{Tselect_Marque2}}": n,"{{Tselect_Marque3}}": o,"{{Tselect_Marque4}}": p,
      "{{Tselect_Marque5}}": q,"{{Tselect_Marque6}}": r,"{{NS}}": v };
      var text = s.getText().asString().trim();
      if (obj[text]) s.replaceWithImage(obj[text]);
    });

    themespictos.getShapes().forEach(s => {
      var obj = { "{{N1}}": ss, "{{N2}}": t,"{{N3}}": u };
      var text = s.getText().asString().trim();
      if (obj[text]) s.replaceWithImage(obj[text]);
    });
    nav.getShapes().forEach(s => {
      var obj = { "{{NS}}": v };
      var text = s.getText().asString().trim();
      if (obj[text]) s.replaceWithImage(obj[text]);
    });
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you have so many variables, you really should just have an array or an object (if you have an array, index 0 should represent `a`, 1 `b`, 2 `c`, etc.), or, you can use an object where its keys are `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. you can loop your array or loop the keys in the object and set the values to `w`

Comment: Hi Nick! Thanks for your comment :) Unsure how to do that though :/

Comment: From your comment `i made a new question thanks anyway` in my answer, I found this question. In your showing script, can I confirm your variables of `a` to `r`? And also, in your showing script, the variables of `ss`, `t``, `u`, and `v` are not declared. I'm worried whether this might be your next issue. So, can you provide your whole script? I think that from your showing script, the script can be modified. But, I thought that when you provide your whole script, the modification points might be found in another part.

Comment: @Tanaike I did declare them, I just didn't include that part of the script here. For further clarification, I edited the question and added the whole script so that you can see

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing your whole script. From your showing script, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, columns "A" to "W" are used. So, `sheet.getRange('A2:DY3').getValues();` can be modified to `sheet.getRange('A2:W3').getValues();`.
- It seems that your script uses 2 rows. When your script is run, when column "A" of both rows has a value, 1st row is used. Please be careful about this. Unfortunately, I cannot know your Spreadsheet. So, I guessed that this might be your expected situation by using one of 2 rows.
- In your situation, the destructuring assignment might be useful.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var brandlogosheet = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kTEoHil6FFLh2ydXaJ9RlU2n5uv9KPjrAhbQY_8hZXE/edit#gid=1309887859"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(brandlogosheet);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('imagescript');
  var values = sheet.getRange('A2:W3').getValues(); // <--- Modified
  var slides = SlidesApp.openById("1pFq0ogk1g1_rXxkahOuvAnksysWShozOet6CzF4BcIk");

  // I modified the below script.
  const [, , , , , , , themespictos, marques, focus, nav] = slides.getSlides();
  values.forEach(val => {
    if (val[0]) {
      const a_r = val.splice(0, 18);
      const [ss, t, u, v, w] = val;
      const [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r] = a_r.map(e => e == "" ? w : e);
      marques.getShapes().forEach(s => {
        var obj = { "{{T1_Marque1}}": a, "{{T1_Marque2}}": b, "{{T1_Marque3}}": c, "{{T1_Marque4}}": d, "{{T2_Marque1}}": e, "{{T2_Marque2}}": f, "{{T2_Marque3}}": g, "{{T2_Marque4}}": h, "{{T3_Marque1}}": i, "{{T3_Marque2}}": j, "{{T3_Marque3}}": k, "{{T3_Marque1}}": l, "{{N1}}": ss, "{{N2}}": t, "{{N3}}": u };
        var text = s.getText().asString().trim();
        if (obj[text]) s.replaceWithImage(obj[text]);
      });
      focus.getShapes().forEach(s => {
        var obj = { "{{Tselect_Marque1}}": m, "{{Tselect_Marque2}}": n, "{{Tselect_Marque3}}": o, "{{Tselect_Marque4}}": p, "{{Tselect_Marque5}}": q, "{{Tselect_Marque6}}": r, "{{NS}}": v };
        var text = s.getText().asString().trim();
        if (obj[text]) s.replaceWithImage(obj[text]);
      });
      themespictos.getShapes().forEach(s => {
        var obj = { "{{N1}}": ss, "{{N2}}": t, "{{N3}}": u };
        var text = s.getText().asString().trim();
        if (obj[text]) s.replaceWithImage(obj[text]);
      });
      nav.getShapes().forEach(s => {
        var obj = { "{{NS}}": v };
        var text = s.getText().asString().trim();
        if (obj[text]) s.replaceWithImage(obj[text]);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- The result of this modified script is the same as your showing script. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Hi Tanaike! Once again, I cannot thank you enough. This really helped! it works perfectly :)